# Javascript in code behind using Literal

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms

I'm trying to write my js code in code behind. I've define a literal called "contentPie" and then put the javascript code in the text of it. But it's not working.

```
contentPie.Text = "<script>window.onload = function() {var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(" + chartContainer + ", { animationEnabled: true,data: [{type: \"pie\",startAngle: 240,indexLabel: \"{label} {y}\",dataPoints: [{ y: 79.45, label: \"Javascript\" },{ y: 7.31, label: \"CSS\" },{ y: 7.06, label: \"Image\" },{ y: 4.91, label: \"HTML\" },{ y: 1.26, label: \"Others\" }]}]});chart.render();}</ script >";
```

P.s, this javascript code is a pie chart template. Here is the source : https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-pie-chart/.

Btw im not sure but << \" >> these tags might be wrong. Let me know if i made a mistake.

Comment: If you need to pass data from the server to a script, you can use `<script type="application/json">...</script>`. You can put a literal inside there and write your data serialized as JSON. Then your client-side script reads that and parses the JSON into an object. It's cleaner because your server code isn't inserting stuff into the client script. It's just supplying values to be read by the JavaScript. If that sounds relevant to what you're doing then I can post an example as an answer.

Comment: In fact, I'd consider encapsulating the whole thing in a `UserControl`. The control owns the script and the literals. If the page needs to communicate with the control at all it's just providing the data. Then that control handles both rendering the script and populating the data that it's going to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not too sure about the reasoning behind writing your client side code on the server side. Usually it's not necessary and not a good practice to do it this way.

But based on your own circumstance, I think you are trying to pass some server side value to the javascript code so that the pie chart can be rendered.

There are a couple of ways of doing this

**Using server side tag**

```
var chartContainer = <%= chartContainerFromCodeBehind %>;
<script>window.onload = function() { // your javascript code... }</ script >
```

**Using [ClientScriptManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) class**

```
var yourJs = "window.onload = function() { ... }";
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "yourKey", yourJsCode,true);
```

Comment: I need some values from server side. I couldn't find another way to do that actually. I tried the <%this.value%> too. Didn't work

Comment: should be `<%=your var %>` or `<%: your var %>`. Did you miss the symbol there?

Comment: yeah i forgot the "=" symbol. I was going to delete the question but just saw you wrote the answer. Thank you so much though :)

Comment: @ovuncdeniz4 happy to help. it'd be much appreciated if you'd also mark the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Append @ in front of Text and Every thing is fine. No need of \" 
use Single Quotes(') inside " 'pie' " Instead of Double quotes(")

```
contentPie.Text = @"<script>window.onload = function() {var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(" + chartContainer + ", { animationEnabled: true,data: [{type: 'pie',startAngle: 240,indexLabel: '{label} {y}',dataPoints: [{ y: 79.45, label: 'Javascript' },{ y: 7.31, label: 'CSS' },{ y: 7.06, label: 'Image' },{ y: 4.91, label: 'HTML' },{ y: 1.26, label: 'Others' }]}]});chart.render();}</ script >";
```

Comment: Not working unfortunately. Did you check the source page? Maybe i'm doing something wrong from the beginning?

Comment: what is the error.
Attach "debugger" javascript keyword in the beginning and then see.

Comment: contentPie.Text = @"<script>debugger; window.onload = function() {......

Comment: 2 errors. "Uncaught syntaxError: unexpected identifier" and "Uncaught Error: Invalid dimensions  for plot, width=null , height=null"  But i did define it in aspx page like this :                                             <div id="chartContainer" clientidmode="static" runat="server" style="width:100%;height:400px;" ></div>